# How to Change the Logout Message in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to change the message **"You are now logged out."**, when the user logs out.
Is there any hook that I can use to modify it?

I've tried using `login_message` or `login_error` filter but does not work.
I don't want to modify `wp-login.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this code in your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'login_message', 'so_13641385_custom_logout_message' );
add_action( 'login_head','so_13641385_custom_login_head' );

// Detect logout or login, and display correspondent message
function so_13641385_custom_logout_message() 
{
    //check to see if it's the logout screen
    if ( isset($_GET['loggedout']) && TRUE == $_GET['loggedout'] ) 
        $message = "<p class='custom-message'>Custom logged out Message.</p><br />";

    //they are logged in
    else 
        $message = "<p class='custom-message'>Custom Login Message.</p><br />";

    return $message;
} 

//outputs the CSS needed to blend custom-message with the normal message
function so_13641385_custom_login_head() 
{
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    #login_error, .message { display:none; }
    .custom-message {
        -moz-border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px;
         border-style:solid;
         border-width:1px;
         margin:0 0 16px 8px;
         padding:12px;
    }
    .login .custom-message {
        background-color:#FFFFE0;
        border-color:#E6DB55;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Replace custom message with your message

Comment: The `Custom Login Message.` will be printed when the login fails (wrong username or password), when it succeeds you're redirected to the dashboard. It's quite a silly security measure, but usually the failed login message is changed to "Error in name or password", instead of the defaults, which denounce what field was wrongly filled.

Answer (score 1):

Use filter **login_messages** not **login_message**

```
function custom_logout_message(){
  return 'You are not login!';
}
add_filter( 'login_messages', 'custom_logout_message' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving on brasofilo's answer:

1. The question does not ask for a log-in message. Provision of such is superfluous.
2. It's superior to use the existing message class rather than defining a custom class and trying to transpose CSS styling.
3. It's best to use filters when they are available.

## Code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_login_errors', 'my_logout_message' );

function my_logout_message( $errors ){

    if ( isset( $errors->errors['loggedout'] ) ){
        $errors->errors['loggedout'][0] = 'Custom Logged-Out Message.';
    }

    return $errors;
}
```